# Find hidden sequence $a_n = a_{n-1} + T $ , with period $T$, given some "random" numbers

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, inference, descriptive-statistics

I have this data plotted on a graph in which all points have the same value on the y-axis, e.g a constant integer "c", while the x-axis is the time in seconds.
So, for a c = 25 on the y-axis, there are points on the graph corresponding to values on the x-axis equals to, let's say,  32, 59, 78, 142, 249, 286, 301, 310, 398, etc..

My goal is to find a sequence (arithmetic progression) of the type

$a_n = a_{n-1} + T $

Where, where $a_n$ is the time in the x-axis and $T$ the period.

I don't know the period $T$ nor the first element of the sequence (and therefore when the sequence begins) and there is white noise (probably most of the points that are in the data are not part of the sequence).

So, in short, I would like to discover a sequence with period $T$ in the middle of a bunch of "random" numbers, given these numbers.

I am thinking first about a brute force algorithm but that would have a running time of $O(n^2)$ but I believe there might be ways to improve or even algorithms that might suit this kind of job. Beforehand, I tried FFT (Fast Fourier Transform), but it did not work on this case because the data is not uniform. Any suggestions on algorithms or ideas to tackle this problem are more than welcome.

Here is the representation of the data on a graph: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ0Qv.png)

Comment: Maybe Poisson point process can give you ideas on how to model this sequence, see for example here: http://robotics.caltech.edu/~zoran/Research/poisson/node1.html